# Port service translation

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I have one public ip and only one inbound port to listen in my machine.

How do I redirect port request based on client service?

For example, my server is listening on `12345` (TCP/UDP) with public ip `35.x.x.x`

If client A use web client (browser) to the `35.x.x.x:12345`, then the request will be forwarded to `127.0.0.1:80` in my machine with webserver on.

If client B use ssh client to the `35.x.x.x:12345`, then the request will be forwarded to `127.0.0.1:22` with ssh server is on in my machine.

If client C play minecraft on server `35.x.x.x:12345`, then the request will be forwarded to `127.0.0.1:19132(udp)` with minecraft server on in my machine.

So how do I do it? I wouldn't mind if I need to setup my server machine as long my clients no need to install anything in their machine.